# Laravel: how can I get the result from eager loading?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have this code in my controller:

```
$users = User::->get();
$users->load('company');
```

The queries:

```
select * from `users` order by `lastname` asc

select * from `companies` where `companies`.`id` in ('4', '9')
```

How can I get the result (collection) form the second query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have a `User belongsTo Company` relation here, so the result of that (not eager, but rather lazy in that case) loading is a single `Model`, not the `Collection`.

That being said you can access related models this way:

```
foreach ($users as $user)
{
  $user->company;
}
```

Now, to fetch the `Collection` of those companies you need this instead:

```
$users = User::all(); // or User::someChainedMethodsHere->get();
$companyIds = $users->fetch('company_id')->toArray(); // assuming company_id is the foreign key
$companies = Company::whereIn('id', $companyIds)->get(); // assuming id is the PK
// returns the Collection you wanted
```

Comment: I think it's a `User hasMany Company` relation because of his second query. It seems like `where companies.id in ...` should be replaced by `where companies.user_id in ...`

Comment: What you suggest is the query for `hasMany`, while the one, you refer to is working for `belongsTo`.

Comment: Its a belongsTo Relation.

When i use this code:

`$companiesIds = array_unique($users->fetch('company_id')->toArray());`
`$companies = Company::whereIn('id', $companiesIds)->get();`
i have two of the same taken Queries:
`select * from companies where companies.id in ('4', '9')`
`select * from companies where id in ('4', '9')`
I use in my View `{{ $user->company->title }}` and i want a list of all Companies on the top of my view?

Comment: Yes, the queries are just the same, but Eloquent treats the result differently. with `load` it matches the companies to the users, while with my suggestion it just stores the result in a collection. So you can then use it in your view: `@foreach($companies as $company) {{ $company->title }} ...`.  I suppose this is what you asked for?